# messageui layout is in English only?

Tags: iphone, localization, messageui

I have implemented the messageUI framework in my project... when I click on the button released emails written form, TO, SUBJECT, SEND, CANCEL .. but the language of my iphone 4 or iphone SIMULATORis in Italian. how to change this layout from English to Italian?
(The format for the messages makes me so)

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on my iOS 4.0 device - and got the same results you are talking about! Seems to me this this is perhaps a big bug in the MessageUI?!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen new programs that have a button connected to a form e-mail and layout in Italian ... messageui safe use, and they work correctly :(